# Class Inheritance Theoretical Insight

Tags: class, oop, inheritance

I was asked recently the following question and wasn't sure how well I did answering it so I wanted to see what people's thoughts were on the question:

If you were dealing with a class of apples and a class of bushels.  What class would inherit from the other and why?

Let me know your thoughts, thanks.

Comment: A bushel-sized basket might *contain* apples, but a bushel is not an apple nor is an apple a bushel. There is little or nothing about them that can be used interchangably (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) or defined with an "is a" relationship.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys.  I thought it was a bit of a trick question, but it's been so long since I did any OOP.  I knew about the "is-a" but I allowed myself to be fooled into thinking a bushel "is a" collection of apples which isn't quite right.  A dog "is an" animal is more along the correct lines of the relationship.  Muchas gracias!

Comment: Even if a bushel was a "collection of apples", you would still not use inheritance, but rather association.

Answer (score 1):

Neither.  Apples are not bushels and bushels are not apples.  Bushels *contain* apples, so the relationship is one of containment, not inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think either class should derived from the other. Apples and bushel baskets are fundamentally different things. A bushel may *contain* apples, but there's no **IS-A** relationship which would suggest inheritance.

Probably the `Apple` class should derive from a more abstract `Fruit` class, while `Bushel` might inherit from some more abstract `Container` class. You could then specify that a `Container` contains zero or more instances of `Fruit`.